# RaspiCam fisheye calibration with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, fisheye

I am trying to calibrate RaspiCam Fisheye lens camera with OpenCV. I am using Python example code and the cheesboard row and column numbers are also correct but somehow I can not get a successful result. I have tested with a lso much of photos below you can see them. My source code: https://github.com/jagracar/OpenCV-python-tests/blob/master/OpenCV-tutorials/cameraCalibration/cameraCalibration.py

my chess board rows and columns: rows = 9, cols = 6

[image: images]

but does not get a successful result

[image: images]

Edit: my solution

https://gist.github.com/mesutpiskin/0412c44bae399adf1f48007f22bdd22d

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Starting with opencv 3, the `fisheye` module was introduced, which manages the calibration for fisheye type lenses quite well. (At least for those who are not familiar with the mathematics behind the calibration process.)

```
# Checkboard dimensions
CHECKERBOARD = (6,9)
subpix_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1)
calibration_flags = cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW
objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[0,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0], 0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)

objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

### read images and for each image:
img = cv2.imread(fname)
img_shape = img.shape[:2]

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Find the chess board corners
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
# If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)
    cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(3,3),(-1,-1),subpix_criteria)
    imgpoints.append(corners)
###

# calculate K & D
N_imm = # number of calibration images
K = np.zeros((3, 3))
D = np.zeros((4, 1))
rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_imm)]
tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float64) for i in range(N_imm)]
retval, K, D, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(
    objpoints,
    imgpoints,
    gray.shape[::-1],
    K,
    D,
    rvecs,
    tvecs,
    calibration_flags,
    (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 1e-6))
```

And now that you have **K** and **D**, you can undistort:

```
img = # your image to undistort
map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), K, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)
undistorted_img = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

this should work!

**UPDATE**[image]

If you want to see the hidden parts of the image (for example the portion outside the yellow box in the above image), after the calibration, you need this:

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img_dim = img.shape[:2][::-1]  

DIM = # dimension of the images used for calibration

scaled_K = K * img_dim[0] / DIM[0]  
scaled_K[2][2] = 1.0  
new_K = cv2.fisheye.estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(scaled_K, D,
    img_dim, np.eye(3), balance=balance)
map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(scaled_K, D, np.eye(3),
    new_K, img_dim, cv2.CV_16SC2)
undist_image = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR,
    borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

Now, by varying the `balance` value you should decrease or increase the size of the final immage (compared to the image above, practically the yellow rectangle).

From OpenCV API: 
`balance`: Sets the new focal length in range between the min focal length and the max focal length. Balance is in range of [0, 1].

Comment: I have a question for you. The edges of the image do not appear. Look at the this link https://image.ibb.co/mg6dKd/Screenshot_2.png

Comment: Your manual to undistort fisheye image is very good, but you forgot to say one important thing. cv2.fisheye works fine if camera FOV less then 180 degrees. When FOV is equal to 180 degrees, the size of undistorted image will be equal to infinity.

Comment: I have a question: How can we make the output of the undistorted image larger? For example, the input image is [640,480]. I want to set the balance to be 0.0 and I want the image to be [1280,960].

Comment: @Frank, this sound more like a CV.resize question to me.

Comment: @VideoProcessingResearcher what is the solution for cameras with FOV of 180 degrees or more?

Comment: Is there no way other than manual adjustment?

Answer (score 3):

First at all, as far as I can see your camera has fisheye optics, but it doesn't give all the surface of fisheye image (usually it is a circle inside black frame).
The second. The code you are using is for usual camera or wide angle (90-110 degrees) It's not for fisheye (~ 180 degrees).
Third. You can use source code URL link from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44650315/9380191)

Comment: hi thanks for answer this should work! but I have a problem The edges of the image do not appear. Look at the this link https://image.ibb.co/mg6dKd/Screenshot_2.png
My Camera specifications 
Aperture (F) : 2.35
Field of View : 160 degree
Diagonal angle : 160 degree
Horizontal angle : 120 degree