# Fisheye camera calibration opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I need to evaluate whether a camera is viewing a 3D real object. To do so I count with the 3D model of the world I am moving and the pose from the robot my camera is attached to. So far, so good, the camera coordinate will be

[x,y,z]' = RX +T

where X is the real object position, and . The camera I am using is a 170º FOV camera, and I need to calibrate it in order to convert these [x,y,z] into pixel coordinates I can evaluate. If the pixel coordinates are bigger than (0,0) and smaller than (width,height) I will consider that the camera is looking at the object.

Can I do a similar test without the conversion to pixel coordinates? I guess not, so I am trying to calibrate the fisheye camera with https://bitbucket.org/amitibo/pyfisheye/src, which is a wrapper over the faulty opencv 3.1.0 fisheye model.

Here is one of my calibration images:
[image]

Using the simplest test ( https://bitbucket.org/amitibo/pyfisheye/src/default/example/test_fisheye.py) This is the comparison with the undistorted image: [image]

It looks really nice, and here is the undistorted:
[image]

How can I get the whole "butterfly" undistorted image? I am currently seeing the lower border...

Comment: Watch my answer to this other question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857278/raspicam-fisheye-calibration-with-opencv/50876130#50876130

Comment: Thanks man! Will give it a look asap